# Guzzle to retrieve page which then submits posts to Elastic Search?

Tags: php, phantomjs, guzzle

I am using Guzzle 6.2 with PHP 5.6.30 on Centos 7 and Apache 2.4

I have a web application (Kibana) on the same server as Guzzle. I would like to retrieve a URL from this web application using Guzzle from a myproxy.php

I am able to get the web application page to start to load on myproxy.php, but the load is not complete. What I've realized is that this web application (Kibana) POSTs data to another application (elastic search) once the page has been loaded and uses the returned data to complete its page build. For reasons I'm not clear on, the POSTs to elastic search appear to not happen when the page is loaded with Guzzle - so the page fails to completely load.

Any ideas on how to use Guzzle to GET a URL, and then allow that URL to issue POSTs which are also sent back to Guzzle?

I'm relatively new to Guzzle and while I've searched and searched for topics on my issue, I realize I may not know the correct terms to search for. Thanks for your patience if this question has been addressed elsewhere.

Comment: On further research, it looks like what I'm looking for is a headless browser and not a proxy which uses cURL. I hadn't used a headless browser before, so I thought I would place this comment in case it helps others. I decided to use PhantomJS for my tests because it acts like a complete browser - allowing the page to load completely before returning it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On further research, it looks like what I'm looking for is a headless browser and not a proxy which uses cURL. I hadn't used a headless browser before, so I thought I would place this comment in case it helps others.

I decided to use PhantomJS for my tests because it acts like a complete browser - allowing the page to load completely before returning it.

here is example code using the onLoadFinished callback:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
  console.log('Status: ' + status);
  // Do other things here...
};
```